# How is Java adding two doubles together when the implementation doesn't specifically tell it to

Tags: java

In doing some research in using EasyMock I decided to pull the tutorial from tutorialspoint located here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/easymock/easymock_junit_integration.htm

Since all the code is there and I'm using exactly that code in eclipse unaltered I won't re-post it unless requested to by one of you.

The problem I'm having is I believe in the understanding of a core Java issue but have been unable to find an answer online. I understand what easymock and junit are doing. I don't understand how the application knows what .add() does. The interface is obviously devoid of any implementation code as it should be. The MathApplication class we are testing against only has:

```
return calcService.add(input1, input2);
```

To me logically I know what I want this to do. I don't understand how the application knows that we mean it to return input1 + input2.

Can anyone help me clear up how the application knows that when calcService.add is called, we want it to add the two inputs?

Comment: You've told it what to do `EasyMock.expect(calcService.add(10.0,20.0)).andReturn(30.00);`

Comment: That's what mocking is: it replaces the actual logic behind an interface/class and simply returns values directly.

Comment: It only knows that the expected return from a method is 30. It doesn't know what the method is doing to return that value and doesn't care.

Comment: Wow I massively overthought that. Very obvious now that you guys said it. Thank you